# bash built-in command "select" not work via pipe in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, select, pipe

I wrote a shell script using bash built-in command **`select`** to create selection menu. It works well when invoking by **`bash`** directly. But if I use pipe `|` such as `cat script.sh | bash`, the **select** function will not work.

For example, code snippet shows

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

arr=("Red Hat" "SUSE" "Debian")
PS3="Choose distribution:"

result=${result:-}

select item in "${arr[@]}"; do
    result="${item}"
    [[ -n "${result}" ]] && break    
done

echo "Result is ${result}"
unset PS3
```

Directly using `bash script.sh`, works well.

```
$ bash /tmp/test.sh 
1) Red Hat
2) SUSE
3) Debian
Choose distribution:1
Result is Red Hat
```

Using pipe `|`, it will output

```
$ cat /tmp/test.sh | bash
1) Red Hat
2) SUSE
3) Debian
Choose distribution:1) Red Hat
2) SUSE
3) Debian
Choose distribution:Choose distribution:Choose distribution:
```

This makes the script not work.

I don't know why? Does `select` do not suppoer pipe `|` or anything else?

Comment: You've created a situation where your script is trying to read from itself, since it inherits its standard input from the `bash` process that runs it. Don't run an interactive script like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`select` reads from stdin.  `stdin` is coming from the pipe.  If you want to get data from the tty, you can try:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

arr=("Red Hat" "SUSE" "Debian")
PS3="Choose distribution:"

result=${result:-}

select item in "${arr[@]}"; do
    result="${item}"
    [[ -n "${result}" ]] && break    
done < /dev/tty                      #  <------------------

echo "Result is ${result}"
unset PS3
```