# How would you pipe options in a shell select loop?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh, posix

My goal is to pipe options from one command to a function that generates a menu using `select`.

Shell select loop reads from `stdin`, which by [default is linked to keyboard inputs](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html), when you are in a pipe however, `stdin` becomes the `stdout` of the previous command (I may be oversimplifying here).

The [bash help says that `select` completes when EOF is read](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#index-select), which is unfortunate, because if you read all options from the pipe, then `select` will not be able to open it, and return immediately.

This is what I would like to do, it does not work:

```
pipe_select() {
        select foo in $(cat <&0)
        do
                echo ${foo};
                break;
        done
}

echo "ga bu zo me" | pipe_select
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more general approach, which allows spaces in select items

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

pipe_select() {
    readarray -t opts
    select foo in "${opts[@]}"
    do  
        echo ${foo};
        break;
    done < /dev/tty
}

printf "%s\n" ga bu zo me | pipe_select
printf "%s\n" "option 1" "option 2" | pipe_select
```

Comment: Thanks, I had not thought about using [`readarray` / `mapfile`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-mapfile) in that way. In my real-world case, I get a JSON payload via `curl` then use `jq` to parse it inside my `select` function.

Comment: readarray is simpler than cat/exec.

Comment: Note that readarray is not available in the current default OSX version of bash (https://stackoverflow.com/q/61647118/411282) or in zsh (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/710369/77539)

Answer (score 1):

[From another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46402174/bash-built-in-command-select-not-work-via-pipe-in-shell-script)

```
pipe_select() {
        opts=$(cat <&0);
        select foo in ${opts}
        do
                echo ${foo};
                break;
        done < /dev/tty
}

echo "ga bu zo me" | pipe_select`
```

That's actually whant I wanted to do all along! :p

Comment: You should accept his answer, or at least upvote it, instead of copying it here.

Comment: Thanks, I upvoted on the other question. (It's already accepted).

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found is the following:

```
pipe_select() {
        opts=$(cat <&0);
        exec <&3 3<&-;
        select foo in ${opts}
        do
                echo ${foo};
                break;
        done
}

exec 3<&0
echo "ga bu zo me" | pipe_select
```

I have a command "generating" options, I use [`exec`](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17974.html) to "save" my `stdin` from the vile corruption of the pipes. When `pipe_select` is called, I parse the output of the previous command, then I "reset" the `stdin` for `select` to read. Everything else is just standard `select` behavior after that.