# Bash 5 - mapfile / readarray command not found

Tags: bash

I am on MacOS Cagalina 10.15.4. I thought mapfile and readarray are available with Bash 4 and later but got below. May I ask what I am doing wrong?

```
$ brew install bash
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin19.4.0)
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

$ mapfile
-bash: mapfile: command not found

$ readarray
-bash: readarray: command not found
```

Comment: If you're using bash try `type -a bash`, since the default `bash` on Mac is `3` you need to locate the path of the new bash and add it to your `PATH` or call the absolute path.

Comment: Use `declare -p BASH_VERSION` to check the current version.

Comment: `bash --version` tells you what version is first in the PATH. It **does not** tell you which version you're currently running.

Comment: @Jetchisel, the OP's PATH is perfectly fine already, as we know since `bash --version` shows the new shell. The problem is that their `/etc/passwd` entry (or whatever modern MacOS uses as an equivalent) is pointing to `/bin/bash` or otherwise something *older* than the shell in the first spot in their PATH. `chsh` or a similar tool will thus be the Right Thing.

Comment: Ok, then `getent passwd mon` should show that yes?

Comment: I have it on my `FreeBSD` here.

Comment: As an alternative to `getent` that I've tested to work on Catalina: `python3 -c 'import pwd, os; print(pwd.getpwuid(os.getuid()).pw_shell)'`